# How to save text into file from UITextView?

Tags: ios, file, io, storyboard, uitextview

I have a storyboard and a textbox. Whenever i enter the text and it should be automatically saved once i press done. And whenever i press Cancel it should rollback to previous state(last saved data). Can anyone give me insight about where to start?

P.S. I am totally new to IOS and Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code about how to write string to file

```
NSString *yourString = yourtextview.text; 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.txt"];
[yourString writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

I suggest you to save string in an NSMutableArray in memory
Every time press done add yourtextview.text object to this array

```
[array addObject:self.textfield.text];
```

Every time press cancel

```
 NSString * lasttext = array.lastObject;
 self.textfield.text = lasttext;
[array removeLastObject];
```

You add a textview on storyboard,and put two button,get outlet of these three.